# Java - String from JSONArray not matching in if statement

Tags: java, arrays

I really can't see where I'm going wrong with this. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have a `JSONArray`

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString);
```

Where responseString is ["prob", "2"]

I get the 1st `String`

```
String maybeProb = jsonArray.getString(0);
```

and when I show it using a Toast all is ok and the toast popup just says prob

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),maybeProb ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But when I use an `if (maybeProb == "prob")` it doesnt return true

Why not??? What am I doing wrong???

Some more details for you:

responseString which forms the original `JSONArray` comes from an `HttpPost` to my server

```
InputStream is = null;

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

is = entity.getContent();

//Convert response to string
responseString = convertStreamToString(is);

public String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {

    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String result = null;

    try
    {           
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"));
      sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line = null;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
      }

      inputStream.close();
      result = sb.toString();

    }
      catch(Exception e)
    {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // return the string
    return result;
}
```

The PHP on my server which makes the response is

```
$message = array("prob", "2");

$response = json_encode($message);

print($response);
```

Many thanks to anyone that can help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare objects in java use `.equals()` method instead of `"=="` operator

Replace the following code

```
 if(maybeProb  == "prob") {
 }
```

with this one.

```
 if(maybeProb.equals("prob")) {
 }
```

Comment: And the problem is no more. Thank you very much, I'm still very new to Java.

Answer (score 2):

The equals operator (`==`) returns true only if both objects are the same, not if their value is the same. Therefore, when you compare the object `maybeProb` with the object `"prob"` it returns `false`

If you want to do the comparison, you have to use `maybeprob.equals("prob")`.